# django or asp.net for business app

Tags: asp.net, django, business-application

I have had experience in asp.net(vb.net) and I'm am looking to create business web app which includes things like reporting, listing of invoice records from DB, creating new invoices, inventory stock, etc.

I hear great things about django but I barely have any experience in python(currently learning) and none in django. Can Django do better than asp.net in making business applications? Asp.net makes things easy with things such as gridview.

Comment: Django is great, But why switch if you already know something that works?

Comment: first of all it's because of all the great things I hear about django and how the productivity that can be achieved is much greater than asp.net.
secondly there is the cost factor. Though I have what I need for the time being, with asp.net being a commercial framework, it is likely in the future that I would have to incur extra costs

Comment: You have answered the question your self. Other than the things you listed above, Django has some nice features which enable you to write good extensible code in a very short time such as generic views, great ORM etc. With these it's amazing how it saves so much time and lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you planning on ultimately deploying. They both are largely capable of be used to write comparable applications. But if you are planning on deploying on windows server, use asp.net; a linux box, write in Django (or Rails, etc).

Comment: consider a situation that,if i made two sites, one with django and another with asp.net.The two sites working and design are the same.Then my question is which one is costly?.Which platform give profit for a software company?

Answer (score 1):

django, because there many solutions for free. For example, [here](https://github.com/)

Sites that use Django: http://www.djangosites.org/